# ReferenceError: document is not defined exited with code=1 in 0.107 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

Sorry if it's a newbie question , i just started coding html,css and javascript and encountered this error-

> ReferenceError: document is not defined**
> -> this issue is only in vscode , when i run this same line on google console it works , now my question is i called the function increase , when i click INCREMENT on website then it should go like 0,1,2,3

````js
```
count = 0;
let constEl = document.getElementById("coun");
function increase() {
  count += 1;
  console.log("CLICKED!");
  constEl.textContent = count;
  console.log(constEl);
}
```
````

```html
~~~<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>People Counter</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>People entered:</h1>
<h2 id="coun">0</h2>
<button id="add_btn" onclick="increase">INCREMENT</button>
<button id="save_btn">Save</button>
<script src="counter.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>~~~
```

My Css Code-

````
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-image: url("station.jpg");
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;

  font-weight: bolder;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
#counter_el {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0ch;
}
button {
  size: 2px;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

#add_btn:hover {
  background-color: limegreen;
  color: white;
}

#add_btn {
  border: 2px solid limegreen;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#save_btn {
  border: 2px solid red;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#save_btn:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}```
````

Comment: in actual code there is no * at script , sorry my bad for typing it here

Comment: Is VSCode configured to run JS in a Node.JS environment? Are you trying to run this in a built-in Node terminal? See [ReferenceError: document is not defined only in Vscode editor](/q/62685661/4642212).

Comment: How exactly are you *running* this code?  Are you opening the page in a browser?  Something else?

Comment: As you can see from the snippet your code works so something else is going on.

Comment: Could you provide the code for the whole page?  We need to see where the javascript is executed

Comment: i am running the code on Vscode (console) and getting this error , but when i go to google developer console and run the same js code it works? so i think it is the issue only with vscode , so how do i do js programing for websites ?? because even the js code which i wrote in vscode doesn't work on website , let me share my updated code

Comment: @ArthChauhan As already explained, the VSCode console runs in a Node.js environment, not in a Web environment.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot everyone ,now i understand it :) and thanks to you guys i am now doing coding and learning javascript frontend